# Detect/Warn on Likely Wrong Locations

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, jobs

I occasionally see positions in "Cambridge, MD" listed in the "Jobs near you" box. Every one of these actually turns out to be a company in Cambridge, **MA**. It might be a good idea for the job-listing submission form to automatically detect this and other likely errors and warn the submitter so that their listing will be shown to people in the correct area, will show up correctly in location searches, etc.

Answer (score 1):

We receive our geo data from Yahoo and sometimes that data isn't so great. I went in a manually massaged the issue. Should be good to until Yahoo gives us some bogus data again.

Comment: I just found (and flagged) two more listings with the same problem that were added after I posted this.

Comment: Yup. I see those. I'll get them fixed up.